# Prove that $x \in \overline A\implies x$ is a limit point

Tags: calculus, geometry

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ (A is a Set), and let $x \in \overline A$ (in other words; x is in the closure of A)

Such that $x$ isn't isolated in $\overline A$.

I need to prove that $x$ is a Limit point? (tried using contradiction but wasn't suceessful)

---

references:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point

**Update: may someone give me at least a hint?**

Comment: Isn't this the definition of closure?

Comment: No, a point $x$ is a limit point of $A$ **iff** for all open $U$ containing $x$ there is a **different** point $y \in U \cap A$. So, if $A=\{0\}$, for example, (note $A$ is closed) then $0$ is not a limit point but is in the closure.

Comment: where do you get stuck?

Comment: I tried to prove that by contradiction so I said x isn't a limit point which means there is open U containing x such that it doesn't contain any points from A except for x

Comment: @user251257 I got stuck here and don't see what I can do further

Comment: @Daniel98: what is the definition of isolated point?

Comment: I have included a reference for that

Comment: any help guys? @copper.hat

Comment: It it not true, I gave you a counterexample?

Comment: how this is not true (It's impossible)? give me an counterexample if you have

Comment: Go to my first comment above.

Comment: this is not a counterexample not any example

Comment: I know the definition very well again you can't find a counterexample

Comment: That's exactly the contradiction!

Comment: I mean that's what it means that x isn't a limit point so what's wrong?

Comment: Can someone help!

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to show that if $x \in \bar{A}$ and $x$ is not an isolated point of $\bar{A}$, then $x$ is a limit point of $\bar{A}$ (which follows immediately from the definitions of isolated and limit point, as commented earlier), or that it is a limit point of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment "I said $x$ isn't a limit point which means there is open $U$ containing $x$ such that it doesn't contain any points from $A$ except for $x$", I think that you are trying to show that

If $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ (A is a Set), $x \in \overline A$, and $x$ is not an isolated point of $\overline A$, then $x$ is a limit point of $A$.

This is not as straightforward as showing that $x$ is a limit point of $\overline A$, which follows immediately from the definitions of ***isolated point*** and ***limit point***, since:

If $x \in \overline A$, and $x$ is not an isolated point of $\overline A$, then there does not exist an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $U \cap (\overline A \setminus \{x\}) = \emptyset$, since if such a $U$ existed $x$ ***would*** be an isolated point, by definition. This means that for every open set $U$ containing $x$, $U \cap (\overline A \setminus \{x\}) \ne\emptyset$, the definition of a limit point.

None of this used the topology of $\mathbb R^n$. It only used the definitions of isolated point and limit point, and is true for any set $A$ in any topological space.

However, it is not true for any set $A$ in any topological space that if $x \in \overline A$, and $x$ is not an isolated point of $\overline A$, then $x$ is a limit point of $A$.

For example, consider the set $X = \{x,y\}$ with the trivial topology, and let $A = \{x\}$. $x \in \overline A = X$, and $x$ is not an isolated point of $\overline A$, since the only open set containing $x$ is $X$, with $X \cap (\overline A \setminus \{x\}) = \{y\} \ne \emptyset$. However, $x$ is not a limit point of $A$, since $X \cap (A \setminus \{x\}) = X \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$.

However, if $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$, (with the usual topology), then it is true that if $x \in \overline A$, and $x$ is not an isolated point of $\overline A$, then $x$ is a limit point of $A$.

To prove this, in a proof by contradiction, assume that $x$ is not a limit point of $A$. Then $x \in \overline A \rightarrow x \in A$ and since $x$ is not a limit point, it is an isolated point of $A$. Let $U$ be an open set containing $x$ such that $U \cap (A \setminus \{x\}) = \emptyset$.

We know that $x$ is a limit point of $\overline A$ (as mentioned earlier), so $U$ necessarily intersects $\overline A$ in some point besides $x$, which we'll call $y$. Thus $y \in \overline A$ but $y \notin A$, so $y$ must be a limit point of $A$.

Let $V$ be any open set containing $y$ but not containing $x$, which exists since $\mathbb R^n$ is a $\mathbf{\text{T}_1}$ $\textbf{space}$.

Then $U \cap V$ is open, $y \in U \cap V$, and $A \cap (U \cap V) = \emptyset$, which contradicts that $y$ is a limit point of $A$.